# Ubuntu Login Loop error

Tags: kernel, root, users, login-screen

My Ubuntu Login is stuck in a loop.When ever I try to login it comes back to the login screen. I have tried various already options Mainly to open console using CTR+ALT+F1 but I wasn't able to login it from there as well. Bash opens up when ever I try to login in the console. Also have tried various solutions related to .Xauthority but whenever I try to use a command containing it says . Xauthority not exits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Tired but it didn't work

Comment: If you had really tried all 30 answers in question 223501, your system would likely be working. Fixing Xauthority, and other possible causes,  is well covered there. Please edit your question to explain what you tried, and the result, in detail.

Comment: it may caused login loop if you edited /etc/profile not right

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, something similar happened to me, I had the automatic login enabled and after updating the system the ubuntu login it would not let me log in

The solution was to comment on the lines of the automatic login accessing from the console in file **/etc/gdm3/custom.conf**

```
#AutomticLoginEnable=true
#AutomaticcLogin=name
```